# How to trigger action inside redux dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I've got an problem with redux. Here is my code:

actions.ts

```
export const getOrders = (id: string) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const queryParams = {
            id,
            search: null,
            order: "DESC",
            status: "all"
        };

        const orders = await api.get('/api/orders', queryParams);
        dispatch(getOrdersSuccess(orders));
    }
}

export const getOrdersSuccess= (payload) => {
    return {
        type: 'GET_ORDERS_SUCCESS',
        payload
    };
}
```

someComponent.ts

```
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getOrders(id)); //here is problem
  }, [dispatch, id])
```

can someone tell me why I cannot use `getIncidents(id)` function inside `dispatch`? When I put this function, VSCode throw me this error:

```
Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<void>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)
```

I have no idea how to fix this :/

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting for `promise` to resolve , then `dispatch` your actions:

`async/await` :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (
    async function handleAsync() {
      let order = await getOrders(id)
      dispatch(order);
    }
  )()
}, [dispatch, id])
```